# Dissolving adjacent parcels by same owner but include those parcels located across street with same owner?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, dissolve

In trying to determine the total contiguous stream length per landowner, I dissolved parcels by parcel owner name attribute and intersected these dissolved parcels with streams.  However, dissolving by parcel owner doesn't include parcels located across the street (right-of-way) when 'Create multipart features' is unchecked since they don't share common edges; and when I do check 'Create multipart features', it creates the desired result across the street but also includes piecemealed parcels per owner that are spread out in space which are not considered contiguous.  I was even thinking of modeling this somehow in Spatial Analyst.  I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 with a basic license.

Any ideas of how to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Can you include another field in the dissolve, such as parcel number or a portion of the parcel number that can tie parcels in close proximity together?

Comment: So separated by a street ROW is contiguous, but by another *n* lots is not? You have cases where a single landowner could have multiple contiguous segments far apart (ie, does it *matter* the single owner parcels are spread out)? I'm thinking a series of intersects, disolves, and explodes would be the only way to do this. Does the segment under the ROW count toward ownership length, or just doesn't count toward non-contiguity?

Comment: Good question, but how close is close? You could try putting the adjacent street name into the polygons and using that as a dissolve field, but what about two frontages - Murphy's law dictates that it will choose the one that you don't want it to. Another approach that has merit is buffer out (XX metres), dissolve (no multipart), buffer in (-XX metres), create centroids, intersect centroids with original, remake polygons then dissolve by intersected FID, join to the intersected data to get your attributes back.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the Spatial Analyst Euclidean Allocation tool to create a seamless parcel layer.  The parcels across the right-of-way share an edge in the output raster.  I convert the raster to a layer and join the original polygon layer to get the final polygon layer.  It is used to determine abutters, with parcels across the street defined as abutting one another.